# Given a diagonalizable linear map, find a basis in which the matrix is strictly upper triangular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, determinant

I have been given the following definition: Let $K$ be a field, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $V$ an $n$-dimensional $K$-vector space. Furthermore $\varphi$ is an Endomorphism of $V$, such that there is a basis $\mathcal{B} = (b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ of $V$ that consists of eigenvectors of $\varphi$.
$\varphi$ is defined as follows: 
$$\varphi(b_i) = a_i b_i \,\text{for} \, (1 \leq i \leq n).$$

My first task was to determine the characteristic polynomial of $\varphi$ and the eigenvalues.
I found that by determining the determinant of:
$$X_\varphi = X_{M_\mathcal{B}^\mathcal{B}(\varphi)} = det(X\cdot E_n - M_\mathcal{B}^\mathcal{B}(\varphi))$$ 
where $M_\mathcal{B}^\mathcal{B}(\varphi)$ is the transformation matrix and $E_n$ is the identity matrix. I found out that the transformation matrix is:
$$M_\mathcal{B}^\mathcal{B}(\varphi) = \left( \begin{array}{cccccc}
   a_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0 \\
   0 & a_2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0 \\
   0 & 0 & a_3 & 0 & \cdots &  0 \\
   \vdots & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &  \vdots \\ 
   0 & &        & 0 & a_{n-1} & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & a_{n} \\
  \end{array} \right) \in K^{n \times n}.$$
So in conclusion we want to determine the determinant of the following matrix:
$$det(X\cdot E_n - M_\mathcal{B}^\mathcal{B}(\varphi)) = \left( \begin{array}{cccccc}
   x - a_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0 \\
   0 & x - a_2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0 \\
   0 & 0 & x - a_3 & 0 & \cdots &  0 \\
   \vdots & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &  \vdots \\ 
   0 & &        & 0 & x- a_{n-1} & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & x- a_{n} \\
  \end{array} \right) \in K^{n \times n}.$$ 
$$\Rightarrow det(X\cdot E_n - M_\mathcal{B}^\mathcal{B}(\varphi)) =  \prod_{i=1}^n (x-a_i). $$
$$\Rightarrow \text{The eigenvalues of $\varphi$ are the $a_i$ for $(1 \leq i \leq n)$}$$
The next task is: What preconditions are required for the eigenvalues of $\varphi$ such that there is a base $\mathcal{C}$ of $V$ such that the matrix $M_\mathcal{C}^\mathcal{C}(\varphi)$ is an upper triangle matrix but not a diagonal matrix. For this task I need to find the condition and the base $\mathcal{C}$. Right now I don't have any ideas of what kind of conditions are required and how the base $\mathcal{C}$ may look.

Comment: Some important mathematical syntax is missing - [see edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3269434/edit). You need to learn to use "such that" and "there is".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is such a basis $\mathcal{C}$ if and only if the $a_i$ are not
>   all equal.

Proof:

If the $a_i$ are all equal then the matrix is diagonal in *any* basis (why?).

If they are not, say $a_1\neq a_2$, then let $\mathcal{C}$ be equal to $\mathcal{B}$ except you replace $b_2$ by $b_1+b_2$. What is the matrix in the basis $\mathcal{C}$?

*Hint:* you need to write $\varphi(c_2)=\varphi(b_1+b_2)=a_1b_1+a_2b_2$ **in terms of** $c_1\,(=b_1)\,$ and $c_2\,(=b_1+b_2)$

Comment: Let $a_2$ be equal to $a_1 + a_2$. Then the image of the linear map for this specific eigenvalue would be: $\varphi(c_2) = a_2 c_2 = (a_1 + a_2)c_2$. Wouldn't this lead to the following transformation matrix: $M_\mathcal{C}^\mathcal{C}(\varphi) = \left( \begin{array}{cccccc}
   a_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0 \\
   0 & a_1 + a_2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0 \\
   0 & 0 & a_3 & 0 & \cdots &  0 \\
   \vdots & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &  \vdots \\ 
   0 & &        & 0 & a_{n-1} & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & a_{n} \\
  \end{array} \right) \in K^{n \times n}.$

Comment: @Nick Sorry, I meant $b_1$, $b_2$ of course. See edit.

Comment: Let $c_2$ be equal to $c_1 + c_2$.  Then the image of the linear map for this specific eigenvalue would be: $\varphi(c_2) = a_2(c_2) = a_2(c_1 + c_2) = a_2c_1 + a_2c_2.$ This would lead to the following transformation matrix: $M_\mathcal{C}^\mathcal{C}(\varphi) = \left( \begin{array}{cccccc}    a_1 & a_2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0 \\    0 & a_2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0 \\    0 & 0 & a_3 & 0 & \cdots &  0 \\    \vdots & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &  \vdots \\     0 & &        & 0 & a_{n-1} & 0 \\    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & a_{n} \\   \end{array} \right) \in K^{n \times n}?$

Comment: @Nick It has this shape all right, but the entries in the second column are wrong. Your computation isn't correct. Use clear notations, such as $c_2=b_1+b_2$, and don't get lost.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry but then I don't know how to calculate the image correctly, especially finding the right transformation matrix.

Comment: @Nick Hint added.

Comment: With your given hint I would assume the following:
$\varphi(c_2) = \varphi(b_1+b_2) = \varphi(b_1) + \varphi(b_2) = a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 = a_1c_1 + a_2(c_2-b_1) = a_1c_1 + a_2c_2 - a_2b_1 = a_1c_1 + a_2c_2 - a_2c_1 = (a_1 - a_2)c_1 + a_2c_2$

Comment: @Nick There you have it. Congrats!

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate you help and your patience :)

Comment: @Nick You're very welcome.